# Html form with dynamic inputs have no text on submit

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, input, enter

I managed to make a form that will let the user add more entries when they hit the enter key (instead of submitting the form).  It all looks good, except when the submit function  is finally called, all the form elements report "undefined" values.

Here is the html:

```
<form id="addItemForm" method="post" action="">
    <p id="form_list_parent">
       <input id="form_list" />
       <br/>
    </p>
   <input type="button" id="additembutton" value="add item" onclick="addAnotherItem()" />
   <br/>
   <input type="button" id="submit_button" value="Submit" onclick='dosubmit()' />
</form>
```

Here is the javascript/jquery:

```
function dosubmit() {
    $('#addItemForm').submit();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //this is intended to prevent enter key from submitting the form
    $('#addItemForm').bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var addbtn = $('#additembutton');
            $(addbtn).click();
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#addItemForm').submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
        log("made it to the form submit function");
        var varz = [];
        var i = 0;
        $('#form_list_parent').find('input').each(function () {
            log("INPUT: " + i);
            //log(dump($(this)));
            var txt = $(this).value;
            log(txt); // always comes back 'undefined' ??
            varz.push(txt);
            i += 1;
        });
        /* Validations go here */
        //this.submit(); // only submit If all the validations succeeded
    });
});

function addAnotherItem() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.id = "dyntext";
    input.name = input.id;
    input.value = "";
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    $('#form_list_parent').append(input);
    $('#form_list_parent').append(br);
    $(input).focus();
}
```

And here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashdottir/UJC5u/4/)

Thanks for any clues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.val()`, because you're using a jQuery selector in which `.value` is not defined.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJC5u/5/)

Your new JavaScript/JQuery:

```
function dosubmit() {
    $('#addItemForm').submit();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //this is intended to prevent enter key from submitting the form
    $('#addItemForm').bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var addbtn = $('#additembutton');
            $(addbtn).click();
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#addItemForm').submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
        log("made it to the form submit function");
        var varz = [];
        var i = 0;
        $('#form_list_parent').find('input').each(function () {
            log("INPUT: " + i);
            //log(dump($(this)));
            var txt = $(this).val();
            log(txt); // always comes back 'undefined' ??
            varz.push(txt);
            i += 1;
        });
        /* Validations go here */
        //this.submit(); // only submit If all the validations succeeded
    });
});

function addAnotherItem() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.id = "dyntext";
    input.name = input.id;
    input.value = "";
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    $('#form_list_parent').append(input);
    $('#form_list_parent').append(br);
    $(input).focus();
}
```